# chart.data from ajax call function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, charts, amcharts

I wanna make a chart with amCharts and have some values that I've recieved from server by ajax call.
now I want to use that data for my chart
can anyone tell me how can i do so?

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  // Add data
  chart.data= (dont want to add data by myself)
  // Add and configure Series
  var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  pieSeries.dataFields.value = "SalePrd";
  pieSeries.dataFields.category = "SaleYear";
```

and data call code

```
var Ajax_URL= url;
  var Year_Val = GetSelectValue("YearSelect");
  var Prd_Val = GetSelectValue("PrdSelect");

  app.request.get(Ajax_URL, { "Token": Token_Data, "SaleYear":Year_Val, "SalePrd":Prd_Val }, function (data)
  {
    var data_Str=''+data;
    var data_Output = JSON.parse(data_Str);
    return data_Output;

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the ajax call,
then draw the chart when the data is returned...

```
var Ajax_URL= url;
var Year_Val = GetSelectValue("YearSelect");
var Prd_Val = GetSelectValue("PrdSelect");

app.request.get(Ajax_URL, { "Token": Token_Data, "SaleYear":Year_Val, "SalePrd":Prd_Val }, function (data)
{
  var data_Str=''+data;
  var data_Output = JSON.parse(data_Str);
  
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  // Add data
  chart.data = data_Output;

  // Add and configure Series
  var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  pieSeries.dataFields.value = "SalePrd";
  pieSeries.dataFields.category = "SaleYear";
  
});
```

Comment: thank you... but it didn't work. it gives me the "value not defined" error

Comment: for which value?

Comment: hmmm... seems like the server has an internal error. but there shouldn't...

Comment: if you are able to get the ajax call to work, will you please share a sample of the data? --> `console.log(data);`